# Aouth 2.0 who to manage 2 authentication type?

Tags: oauth

There is a food ordering system. There are around 12 or 13 APIs.

The end-user can search for restaurants, foods, filter things, etc. without logging in to the system. The login is only necessary for placing an order, see past orders etc. So, for like 10 APIs I don't need the user to login.

**10 APIs (need to verify the third-party)**

**The rest (need to verify the third-party as well as the user)**

The oAuth 2.0 solutions I have seen so far, they instantly asks for the users to login which is something I don't want.

It'd be really helpful for me if someone takes the time to explain a possible solution and how all those could fit together.

Answer (score 0):

If no Authentication is required, then the information is "Public" and does not need protection from OAuth 2.0.

It would not be unusual for a APIs to be called by a WEB Application where the WEB Application needs to use OAuth 2.0 to access the APIs, but the end-user has no relation to the APIs. So the WEB Application needs an OAuth 2.0 client_id for access to the APIs. The client credentials grant is designed for this use-case: ([RFC 6749 Section 1.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4))

> when the authorization scope is limited to the protected resources
> under the control of the client ... when the client is acting on its
> own behalf

The WEB Application may then at some point use OpenID Connect to Authenticate the end-user for access to some of the "protected resources".